# how to resize an object to fit another?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to size the mesh outlined to the left object. What is the best way considering that the resizing needs to be proportional..[image]

Comment: Probably regular scaling on 3 axis, and snapping to some other mesh geometry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could use the absolute bounding box. Setting the dimensions of your right object to the dimensions of the left one should give pretty good results:

[image: screenshot]

**Note** You'll probably have to watch out for the **y** value. Make sure to use the same ratio as for **x** and **z** to prevent the object from stretching.